# SharePoint online - Published content type is not available to select when trying to add it

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, administration, content-type-hub

We have a centrally published content type which had been published since over a week. If I check the Content type gallery on my site the content type is listed with the following warning:

> "This content type is published but yet to be used in this site. Once it is used, it will be synced to the site and can be edited."

If I go to 'Site pages > Add column > Add a content type' there is no available content type there. The dropdown menu stays grey.

Does anyone know how can I use the content type to be synced when I can't add it?

Comment: Did you create this content type at site collection level or tenant level? What is the parent content type of it? Did you try adding content type from library settings (classic experience)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
It had been created in tenant level, the parent content type is "item". 
If I go to library settings and Add from existing site content types, my content type is not listed there.

Answer (score 0):

If your parent content type is Item, then I don't think it will be selectable for use within a document library (or the Site Pages library). It should be available for use within a list.

Try creating your content type using Document as the parent.

Comment: If I create the content type from the site directly, and use the parent content type item, then I can use it in the Site pages library. I would need the content type to be available tenant wide, so we I recreated the same, which is then not available. For lists I can not add a content type and under the custom columns, the columns of my content type are not listed.